# Kong route and upstream server path

Tags: uri, kong, kong-plugin

I have the following configuration of service with route in Kong:

```yaml
- name: test
  host: test-service
  port: 80
  protocol: http
  path: /endpoint/
  routes:
    - name: test_route
      strip_path: true
      preserve_host: true
      paths:
        - /login
```

I am trying to understand the following behaviour:

- when I access `http://localhost/login`, I will end up with the `http://localhost/endpoint` in my browser
- however, when I try to access `http://localhost/login/test/page`, nothing will change and I am still in my browser on `http://localhost/login/test/page` and the upstream server served my request properly

My expectation was that using `http://localhost/login/test/page`, my browser will have eventually `http://localhost/endpoint/test/page`. Apparently I misunderstood it.

I understood that in this case, Kong will use the upstream path as `/endpoint/test/page`, because I have `strip_path: true`.

However, how it can be changed in case I want to end up with `http://localhost/endpoint/test/page` in case I will access `http://localhost/login/test/page` in my browser?

Answer (score 0):

I test your case in my lab. And it's working.

```
[07/Aug/2023:06:43:22 +0000] "GET /endpoint/123 HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
```

When I curl /login/123